# CORS React - net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED 2022

Tags: reactjs

really new coder here.

After 2 days and reading a lot of stack post about this issue with no resolve, I am in dire need of help - I don't want to give up.

My code:

```
// useFetch.js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useFetch = (url) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            fetch(url)
                .then(res => {
                    if (!res.ok) {
                        throw Error('could not fetch the data for that resource');
                    }
                    return res.json();
                })
                .then(data => {
                    setIsPending(false);
                    setData(data);
                    setError(null);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    setIsPending(false);
                    setError(err.message);
                })
        }, 1000);
    }, [url])

    return { data, isPending, error };
}

export default useFetch;
_____________________________________________________________________
// Home.js
import BlogList from "./BlogList";
import useFetch from "./useFetch";

const Home = () => {
  const { data: blogs, isPending, error } = useFetch('http://localhost:8000/blogs')

  return (
    <div className="home">
```

I have tried

- disabling 'Enable javascript in source maps' and disabling 'Enable css source maps'
- Clearing cache and making sure chrome is updated
- putting the proxy method in package.json

I thank you very much in advance.

Comment: please post code, not images of code ...

Comment: changed from screen cap to pasted code.

Comment: Hi :). Whilst correct that you shouldn't post images, you now completely removed the error message. Could you copy the error in the console as text and post it here? Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be making a request to `localhost:8000`. What is running on that URL? Could you also post the code of that?

Answer (score 0):

1- Cors is a problem you should fix in your server code (if it's nodejs you could try installing cors package)
Or you could try installing browser extension to allow CORS .
There's a lot of those in chrome or opera no need to recommend one.

2-The error that's in your console doesn't seem to be CORS related.
Your client doesn't seem to find the server so maybe check that the server is running first.

Good luck and don't give up :D

Comment: Hello! Thank you lots for the reply! - Forgot to mention that i tried using CORS extension and i get the same thing.


Server you mean npm start? or how do make I make sure my server is running?

Thanks again!

Comment: Ok the way it works is so : there's your front-end code which in your case is react that runs in the user's browser . When your code needs dynamic data it will need to call a server or you can call it back-end . in this case you use fetch to call a another program (the back-end) asking for blogs. in your case i see you're following a tutorial that is working with react and another program which is a back-end server that returns the blogs

Comment: If you need to fetch data but you don't want to start learning a backend technology you can use JSON Placeholder that gives placeholder data you can use

Comment: try replacing localhost:8000/blog by https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1. It should return a todo but make sure you console.log first to see the result. SIDE NOTE : try looking at how http works might help you learn stuff easier

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshots, your site (React development server) appears to be running on `http://localhost:3000`, but fetches `http://localhost:8000/blogs`. Make sure that the fetch url is correct and if it is, make sure that second server on port 8000 is actually running.

Comment: Hi there. I tried changing the link and it gives me this. 'Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0' BUT no error on dev tools - as far as double checking the ports can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @operator-19 try opening the developer console, go to the network tab, and refresh the page. Then click on the request and select response. You should then see what the server responded with. My guess is, that you are JSON parsing the response, but the server sends HTML because there was an error, or sends XML instead of JSON.